# Internal Link building strategy

Tags: seo, links, link-building

I am having a few concerns about the best possible link building strategy for a large webshop.

The category structure is something like this:

```
www.site.com
www.site.com/whitegoods
www.site.com/whitegoods/washing-machines
www.site.com/whitegoods/washing-machines/front-loaded
www.site.com/whitegoods/washing-machines/front-loaded/siemens
```

Now I want `www.site.com/whitegoods/washing-machines` to rank for the search *washing machines* which is highly competitive.

And I want `www.site.com/whitegoods/washing-machines/front-loaded/siemens` to rank for search terms like *front loaded washing machines* which is not very competitive.

Normally you say that you want to pass PR down through the page structure but the page that really needs some juice is the `www.site.com/whitegoods/washing-machines` page that I want to rank for *washing machines*.

In other words: is it a good or a bad strategy to link from `www.site.com/whitegoods/washing-machines/front-loaded/siemens` to `www.site.com/whitegoods/washing-machines` with the anchor text *washing machines*?

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUBLICATE OF THE SUGGESTED POST AT ALL. It is linkbuilding in the content and has nothing to do with url structure...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so - using this:

> In other words: is it a good or a bad strategy to link from
>   `www.site.com/whitegoods/washing-machines/front-loaded/siemens` to
>   `www.site.com/whitegoods/washing-machines` with the anchor text *washing
>   machines*?

The answer is *yes*. Since you are already in a context known as *washing machines* - its uninformative and redundant to alt tag just that. However, if the mechanism you are using to direct a user "up a tier" in the navigation, does indeed satisfy that level of ambiguity then thats simply the fact of the matter. However - Siemens does more than washing machines, perhaps you sell other siemens products.

Moreso - if this "link" is a portion of a breadcrumb - you could still use *washing machines* as the display text but perhaps a more informative description in the `alt` tag.